# How to pass form data as route parameters in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I want to use the value of only one field of a form with two fields as a route parameter to a controller. What I achieve so far was only a mess of query string parameters appended to the url.

My form:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['anuncio.especificar_tipo_imovel', $valorCep = 'valorCEp'],  'method' => 'GET']) }}
    <input type="hidden" value="14405024" id="valorCep" name="valorCep"/>
    <label for="tbCep"/>
        <input autocomplete="off" id="tbCep" style="width:400px;" name="cep" type="text" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="continuar">
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I have a route like this:

```
Route::get('anuncio/especificar_tipo_imovel/{valorCep}', [
    'as' => 'anuncio.especificar_tipo_imovel',
    'uses' => 'AnuncioController@especificar_tipo_imovel'
]);
```

and a action method like this

```
public function especificar_tipo_imovel(Request $request, $valorCep)
{  
   return view('especificar_tipo_imovel');
}
```

The value I want to send is the value of the hidden field: valorCep
I want a url like 
    `http://my_route/34834839`
the number beeing the value of the hidden field and the `$valorCep` route parameter.

my url is this way:

```
http://my_route/valorCEp?valorCep=14405024&cep=Rua++jardim+pedreiras14405024
```

Comment: $xxxx=$request->valorCep; you can use like this

Comment: My problem is not to get the value in the controller. My problem is the url format.

Comment: sorry,not getting exactly what you want??

Comment: the last line of my question show my url when I submit the form. I want a url formatted this way http://my_route/valorCep.I only have seen people using route parameters by typing directly into the url, I would like to know How to pass the parameters programatically. I want a url similar to that of stackoverflow :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are assigning `$valorCep` in the view with the literal 'valorCep'. You should pass it from your controller.

```
public function especificar_tipo_imovel(Request $request, $valorCep)
{
    return view('especificar_tipo_imovel', ['valorCep' => $valorCep]);
}
```

and in your view:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['anuncio.especificar_tipo_imovel', $valorCep],  'method' => 'GET']) }}
```

Comment: I know that with the literal 'valorCep' I won't get any dinamic routing. I just use it to show where I am stuck and what I am trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what are you trying now, you can create a route by passing the query parameters as key value pairs. Look: 

`['route' => ['anuncio.especificar_tipo_imovel', 'valorCep' => $valorCep, 'cep' => $cep]]`

However, you should assert no name collisions between query and route parameter names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
public function especificar_tipo_imovel(Request $request, $cep)
{
    $valorCep = $request->valorCep;

    return view('especificar_tipo_imovel', ['valorCep' => $valorCep]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the value of the hidden input to the route like this `$valorCep = 'valorCEp'`, that way you are just passing the string **'valorCEp'** as the parameter. Check your url, is the route with the parameter being the string, plus the input's values (cause the GET method).

Unless you have the value of valorCep input in a variable, and pass this variable instead the 'valorCEp' string, you will need some javascript. Something like this:

Script (with jQuery)

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var valorCep = $('#valorCep').val();
    $('form').attr('action', 'anuncio/especificar_tipo_imovel/'+valorCep);
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work, the value of the inputs is sended